# Eclipse-mosquitto "Address not available"

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I am new to mqtt and am trying to simply start a local instance with which I can test.

When executing

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 --restart always -v mosquitto.conf:/home/juliette/mosquito.conf --name mqtt eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.7
```

I get the following output:

```
1615963221: mosquitto version 2.0.7 starting
1615963221: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1615963221: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1615963221: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1615963221: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1615963221: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1615963221: Error: Address not available
1615963221: mosquitto version 2.0.7 running
```

and cannot connect with a mqtt-client:

```
mqtt sub --topic test
Server closed connection without DISCONNECT.
```

From what I've found the error apparently happens when no listener is configured but I did configure one, this is my mosquito.conf:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
port 1883
```

I also tried changing the port to 8883 because in one post someone mentioned that a larger port might solve the problem but that also didn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `port 1883` from the end of the config file, you have already told it to use that port as part of the listener on the first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your startup command is close, but not correct.  It should be:

```
docker run -it \
  -p 1883:1883 \
  --restart always \
  -v /home/juliette/mosquito.conf:/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf \
  --name mqtt \
  eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.7
```

The config file is in `/etc/mosquitto`...unless they have moved it in version 2.

You might also want to add a `-p 8333:8333` line for mqtts/TLS connections.

EDIT:  I see up in your log file output it says that the config was loaded from `/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` ...so if the `-v /home/juliette/mosquito.conf:/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` line does not work, change it to `-v /home/juliette/mosquito.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: thanks, that fixed my problem. I mixed up the order of local path and container path in the parameters

Comment: FYI, the default MQTTS/TLS port is 8883, not 8333.